# Storing values in gdb while debugging

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am debugging a program and find myself doing this all the time

```
(gdb) p edges[i]
$9 = (std::pair<int, int> &) @0x7ffff427b790: {first = 26349, second = 25679}
(gdb) p nodes[26349].parent
$10 = 25679
```

what I would like to do is something like

```
(gdb) v = edges[i]
(gdb) p nodes[v.first].parent
$11 = 25679
```

The variable v is only a short hand notation/alias for edges[i]. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. This is called convenience variables in gdb and has the following syntax:

```
(gdb) set $v = edges[i]
(gdb) p nodes[$v.first].parent
$11 = 25679
```

The line which reads `$11 = 25679` stores also stores the last value in a convenience variable so you can do `p $11`. Nifty